# Displaying number of images in Android application with scroll view. I think the images should be kept in list view

Tags: android, image

I want to display images on Android screen. The images should be scrolled vertically. How should I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps I am mentioning below,

1. take one Scroll View with Vertical Scroll
2. Add one Linear Layout in it with Vertical Orientation
3. Now, What you have to do is, Programatically in your code retrieve the images one by one and add the ImageView in the Linear Layout and assign the Image to that ImageView.
4. Keep the height and width of the Imageview and other Layouts as per your requirement.
5. This way you will have all the images same like a PDF pages format...